# Values from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a new class within my SKScene class called `ForceTouch`. This is of type `UIView`. Not sure if this is correct to do but it seems to have taken the errors away.
My question is; I have calculated a value within my `ForceTouch` class and wish to use it in my `SKScene` class. Is it possible to do this? 
Below is a copy of my code:

`class ForceTouch: UIView {`

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first where traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {

        let relativeForce = touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce
        let forceMultiplier: CGFloat = 100
        let playerFlight = CGFloat(relativeForce) * CGFloat(forceMultiplier)
        var playerVelocity = CGPoint.zero
        func flyPlayer() {
            playerVelocity = CGPoint(x: 0, y: playerFlight)
        }

        flyPlayer()

        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use the value I have calculated for `playerVelocity` and use it later on in the code: outside of my `ForceTouch` class.
When I attempt to do so I get an error "use of unresolved identifier - playerVelocity".
Please could anybody give me some help as to how I rectify this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi yes, I wish to use the `playerVelocity` value if possible within my `SKScene` class

Comment: Just declare it as optional class variable only instead of a local variable within the function. And get used to some basic OOP principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use `playerVelocity` value diractly from your `ForceTouch` class then you can do it for example like this:

```
class ForceTouch: UIView {

    var playerVelocity = CGPoint.zero

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first where traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
            let relativeForce = touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce
            let forceMultiplier: CGFloat = 100
            let playerFlight = CGFloat(relativeForce) * CGFloat(forceMultiplier)
            func flyPlayer() {
                playerVelocity = CGPoint(x: 0, y: playerFlight)
            }

            flyPlayer()
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `SKScene` class get it from `ForceTouch` object like `forceTouch.playerVelocity` where `forceTouch` is object of `ForceTouch` class that you have in your `SKScene` class

Or if you need send `playerVelocity` to parrent class after some action you need to use delegation mechanism

Comment: Excellent that's worked perfectly. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question!